# SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

Tags: python

```
a=input(int('Введите стоимость радиорелейной линии связи: '))
b=input(int('Введите стоимость кабельной линии связи: '))
c=input(int('Введите стоимость лазерной линии связи: '))
d=input(int('Введите количество линий: '))
A=(a*d)
B=(b*d)
C=(c*d)
if ((A<B) and (A<C)):
print('Радиорелейная линия-самый экономный вариант')
else ((B<A) and (B<C)):
print('Кабелная линия-самый экономный вариант')
else ((C<A) and (C<B)):
print('Лазерная линия-самый экономный вариант')
else print ('Каналов недостаточно')
```

Comment: Откройте любой учебник и почитайте синтаксис if-else

Comment: и ещё с отступами что-то не то

Comment: @Qwertiy отступы, наверно, при копипасте на сайт потерялись, стандартная ситуация

Comment: Объясните,пожалуйста, что не так в первых строках

Comment: @Arseniy в первых четырёх строках вы пытаетесь получить из строки число, а питон не умеет интерпретировать `Введите стоимость радиорелейной линии связи: ` как какое-то число

Answer (score 1):

```
a = int(input('Введите стоимость радиорелейной линии связи: '))
b = int(input('Введите стоимость кабельной линии связи: '))
c = int(input('Введите стоимость лазерной линии связи: '))
d = int(input('Введите количество линий: '))

if ((A<B) and (A<C)):
    print('Радиорелейная линия-самый экономный вариант')
elif ((B<A) and (B<C)):
    print('Кабелная линия-самый экономный вариант')
elif ((C<A) and (C<B)):
    print('Лазерная линия-самый экономный вариант')
else:
    print ('Каналов недостаточно')
```