# Объясните, что не правильно в коде?

Tags: python

```
a = int(input('Введите первое число: '))
b = int(input('Введите второе число: '))
c = int(input('Введите третье число: '))
d = int(input('Введите четвертое число: '))
if a > b and a > c and a > d:
    a = r
elif b > a and b > c and b > d:
    b = r
elif c > a and c > b and c > d:
    c = r
else:
    d = r

P = a * b * c * d
X = P / r

print ('P: '(P))
print ('X: '(X))
```

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что в коде что-то неправильно?

Comment: После ввода данных возникает ошибка

Comment: какая ошибка возникает дополните вопрос

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/809544/syntaxerror-multiple-statements-found-while-compiling-a-single-statement)

Answer (score 3):

Не знаю, что у Вас неправильно, но присвоения, которые я вижу:

a = r

b = r

c = r

d = r

и операция

X=P/r

выполняются ДО ТОГО, как переменная r  примет какое-нибудь значение. Эта ошибка не только в Python. Это ошибка в любом языке программирвоания.

Comment: Не подскажете, как должно быть?

Comment: Я же не знаю, что вы сделать-то хотите. Может задать вначале r=10000. Может написать r=a, r=b  и т.д. Это уже семантика, а не синтаксис. Я описал вашу ошибку. А уж как править - задача ваша.

Answer (score 1):

В блоке каждого условия, вместо:

```
a = r
```

пиши

```
r = a
```

Никогда не забывай, что переменной слева ПРИСВАИВАЕТСЯ значение выражения справа.
И объясняй в вопросах, что не так с твоей программой более понятно.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = int(input('Введите первое число: '))
b = int(input('Введите второе число: '))
c = int(input('Введите третье число: '))
d = int(input('Введите четвертое число: '))
if a > b and a > c and a > d:
    r = a
elif b > a and b > c and b > d:
    r = b
elif c > a and c > b and c > d:
    r = c
else:
    r = d

P = a * b * c * d
X = P / r

print ('P: ', P)
print ('X: ', X)
```

Попробуй так

Comment: А как сработает ваш алгоритм, если все четыре введенные числа будут одинаковыми? Или даже хотя-бы два из них?

Answer (score 0):

Если уж рефакторить, так рефакторить

```
from functools import reduce                                                    
from operator import mul                                                        

names = ('первое', 'второе', 'третье', 'четвертое')                             
vars = [int(input('Введите {} число: '.format(n))) for n in names]              

P = reduce(mul, vars, 1)                                                        
X = P/max(vars)                                                                 

print('P: ', P)                                                                 
print('X: ', X)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python читает код как и человек: слева-направо, сверху-вниз. Поэтому, когда вы

```
if a > b and a > c and a > d:
    a = r
```

пишите a=r, то Python читает это, как: "присвоить переменной a значение переменной r", не наоборот! И, т.к. переменная r до этого не объявлялась, появляется исключение NameError. Поэтому, @Никита Вавилов откорректировал ваш код правильно.